# Executing PHP scripts using crontab

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I am trying to execute a PHP script using crontab but it doesn't seem to work. I am running AWS EC2 Linux and here is the PHP script:

```
  FOREACH (GLOB("*.jpg") AS $filename) {
     ECHO "$filename size " . FILESIZE($filename) . "\n";
     UNLINK($filename);
  }

  FOREACH (GLOB("*.jpeg") AS $filename) {
     ECHO "$filename size " . FILESIZE($filename) . "\n";
     UNLINK($filename);
  }

  FOREACH (GLOB("*.gif") AS $filename) {
     ECHO "$filename size " . FILESIZE($filename) . "\n";
     UNLINK($filename);
  }

  FOREACH (GLOB("*.png") AS $filename) {
     ECHO "$filename size " . FILESIZE($filename) . "\n";
     UNLINK($filename);
  }
```

When I execute this script manually from a browser, it works normally. But it doesn't work using crontab

Here is my cron command:

```
00 * * * * php /var/www/html/*****/*****/delete.php
```

And here is the log:

> Nov 28 02:12:01 ip-##-##-##-## CROND[#####]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php
>   /var/www/html/*****/*****/delete.php)

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Your calls to glob aren't specifyng a full directory path, so they're looking for files in the current directory and you might need to make sure the script runs with the correct current directory.  e.g.  `00 * * * * cd <some-directory> && php /var/www/html/*****/*****/delete.php`

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue... 
[Cron is setup correct (I think) but is not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52525312/cron-is-setup-correct-i-think-but-is-not-running/52534449#52534449)

It is now working for me:

edit /etc/crontab directly and be sure to check your paths.
(You can even cd into the correct directory like this, perhaps that will solve your issue too..)

```
00 * * * * cd /var/www/html/*****/*****/ && php ./delete.php
```

Also check if just php will do the trick.
call:

```
which php
```

to see the full path of PHP and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working fine in browser then you can set the cron job as below,

```
00 * * * * wget -q -O /dev/null http://example.com/delete.php
```

this will work same like you calling in browser just change the "http://example.com/delete.php" with the url which you call in browser.