# Cron is setup correct (I think) but is not running

Tags: php, cron, centos7

I have set some commands in my crontab, but it seems like they are not executed.

- PHP version is 7+
- CentOS 7

This is my list when I run "crontab -u username -l"

```
45 0 * * * username /usr/bin/php /var/www/production/site/scripts/process1.php
*/2 * * * * username /usr/bin/php /var/www/production/site/scripts/process2.php
25 * * * * username /usr/bin/php /var/www/production/api/scripts/process3.php
```

username is an existing user and has rights to the PHP files. Same results when I use the root user.

When I run "Which php" I get the result below:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

So that seems to be OK too.

/var/log/cron shows me lines like this, so it appears to be called

```
CROND[29053]: (username) CMD (username /usr/bin/php /var/www/production/site/scripts/process1.php)
```

When I run the commands manually all works well, so the processx.php files seem to be OK.

I am running out of ideas... Can anybody point me to the right direction to tackle my (probably silly) mistake?

Comment: "/var/bin/php" vs. "/usr/bin/php" ? which one is now correct?

Comment: /usr/bin/php is correct, double checked. Just a typo in this post sadly... edited it in my mainpost

Comment: So if the log shows the file being run, this problem is nothing to do with `cron`, correct? Have you tried running the script as `username`?

Comment: When I run the commands like this: "/usr/bin/php /var/www/production/api/scripts/process3.php" it all runs well and all is working without issues.

Comment: You shouldn't have `username` at the beginning of the commands. That's only needed in the system-wide `/etc/crontab`, not the per-user crontabs.

Comment: Have you checked the user's email, they should have gotten mail with the output of the command.

Comment: I have now removed the username from the command in the crontab. Still nothing. Also added a row in the processx.php file to send me an email when run, but no emails are being received. So it seems like it is NOT running...

Comment: Do something simpler, create a folder with 777 as permission and do a `file_put_contents('/absolute/path/to/folder/test.log', 'Executed');` in the top of your file and check if the file is created and contains "Executed".

Comment: Just a hunch: Is there a newline character at the end of the last command in your crontab? According to the man page on my system "cron requires that each entry in a crontab end in a newline character. If the last entry in a crontab is missing a newline (ie, terminated by EOF), cron will consider the crontab (at least partially) broken. A warning will be written to syslog."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it is working... Still not 100% sure why it was not before.
But this is what I changed:

removed the processes with the command "crontab -e" and deleted the 3 commands there.
Then:

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

Added the commands there (with the right user to execute them) e voila!

Difference was that I used /etc/crontab directly and not using crontab -e.

Although I am now still curious why this is working and my first attempt through crontab -e is not... So, if anybody knows why, please let me know!